MUI Table not rendering onPageChange and onRowsPerPageChange
I am using next js serverSideProps to feed the data into my component. All the data is getting displayed, but even when the initial rowsPerPage = 5, the table displays all the items. Even if I change the rowsPerPage, and the page number, nothing happens.
Here is the parent compoent (all data is present props):
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import PlusIcon from '@untitled-ui/icons-react/build/esm/Plus';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import SvgIcon from '@mui/material/SvgIcon';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { ordersServices } from '@/services/order-services';
import { OrderDrawer } from '@/sections/order/order-drawer';
import { OrderListContainer } from '@/sections/order/order-list-container';
import { OrderListTable } from '@/sections/order/order-list-table';
import { OrderListSearch } from '@/sections/order/order-list-search';
import { Order } from '@/schemas/order';
import { Layout as DashboardLayout } from 'src/layouts/dashboard/layout';
import { useDialog } from '@/hooks/use-dialog';
import { useMounted } from '@/hooks/use-mounted';

const useOrdersSearch = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    filters: {
      query: undefined,
      status: undefined,
    },
    page: 0,
    rowsPerPage: 5,
    sortBy: 'createdAt',
    sortDir: 'desc',
  });

  const handleFiltersChange = useCallback((filters: any) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      filters,
    }));
  }, []);

  const handleSortChange = useCallback((sortDir: any) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      sortDir,
    }));
  }, []);

  const handlePageChange = useCallback((event: any, page: any) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      page,
    }));
  }, []);

  const handleRowsPerPageChange = useCallback((event: any) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      rowsPerPage: parseInt(event.target.value, 10),
    }));
  }, []);

  return {
    handleFiltersChange,
    handleSortChange,
    handlePageChange,
    handleRowsPerPageChange,
    state,
  };
};

const useCurrentOrder = (orders: Order[], orderId: string | undefined) => {
  return useMemo(() => {
    if (!orderId) {
      return undefined;
    }

    return orders.find((order) => order._id === orderId);
  }, [orders, orderId]);
};

const Page = (props: any) => {

  const rootRef = useRef(null);
  const ordersSearch = useOrdersSearch();
  const dialog = useDialog();

  const [ordersStore, setOrderStore] = useState({
    orders: [],
    ordersCount: 0,
  });

  const currentOrder = useCurrentOrder(ordersStore.orders, dialog.data);

  const isMounted = useMounted();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted()) {
      setOrderStore({
        orders: props.allOrders,
        ordersCount: props.allOrders.length,
      });
    }
  }, [isMounted, props.allOrders]);

  const handleOrderOpen = useCallback(
    (orderId: string) => {
      // Close drawer if is the same order
      if (dialog.open && dialog.data === orderId) {
        dialog.handleClose();
        return;
      }

      dialog.handleOpen(orderId);
    },
    [dialog]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Divider />
      <Box
        component="main"
        ref={rootRef}
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          flex: '1 1 auto',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          position: 'relative',
        }}
      >
        <Box
          ref={rootRef}
          sx={{
            bottom: 0,
            display: 'flex',
            left: 0,
            position: 'absolute',
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
          }}
        >
          <OrderListContainer open={dialog.open}>
            <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
              <Stack
                alignItems="flex-start"
                direction="row"
                justifyContent="space-between"
                spacing={4}
              >
                <div>
                  <Typography variant="h4">Porudžbenice</Typography>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <Button
                    startIcon={
                      <SvgIcon>
                        <PlusIcon />
                      </SvgIcon>
                    }
                    variant="contained"
                  >
                    Dodaj
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </Stack>
            </Box>
            <Divider />
            <OrderListSearch
              onFiltersChange={ordersSearch.handleFiltersChange}
              onSortChange={ordersSearch.handleSortChange}
              sortBy={ordersSearch.state.sortBy}
              sortDir={ordersSearch.state.sortDir}
            />
            <Divider />
            <OrderListTable
              count={ordersStore.ordersCount}
              items={ordersStore.orders}
              onPageChange={ordersSearch.handlePageChange}
              onRowsPerPageChange={ordersSearch.handleRowsPerPageChange}
              onSelect={handleOrderOpen}
              page={ordersSearch.state.page}
              rowsPerPage={ordersSearch.state.rowsPerPage}
            />
          </OrderListContainer>
          <OrderDrawer
            container={rootRef.current}
            onClose={dialog.handleClose}
            open={dialog.open}
            order={currentOrder}
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context: any) {
  try {

    const allOrders = await ordersServices().getAllOrders();

    return {
      props: {
        allOrders: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(allOrders)),
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching orders:', error);
    return {
      props: {
        allOrders: [],
      },
    };
  }
}

Page.getLayout = (page: any) => <DashboardLayout>{page}</DashboardLayout>;

export default Page;


And here is the table component:
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import numeral from 'numeral';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TablePagination from '@mui/material/TablePagination';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { SeverityPill } from 'src/components/severity-pill';
import { Order } from '@/schemas/order';

export const OrderListTable = (props: any) => {
  const {
    count = 0,
    items = [],
    onPageChange = () => { },
    onRowsPerPageChange,
    onSelect,
    page = 0,
    rowsPerPage = 0,
  } = props;

  console.log('page', page);
  console.log('rowsPerPage', rowsPerPage);


  const handlePageChange = (event: any, newPage: number) => {
    console.log('event', event);
    console.log('newPage', newPage);

    onPageChange(event, newPage); // Ensure correct parameters are passed
  };

  const handleRowsPerPageChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    onRowsPerPageChange(event); // Handle the change in the number of rows per page
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="center">Datum</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Broj porudžbenice</TableCell>
            <TableCell align='left'>Suma</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Način plaćanja</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Ime</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Email</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="left">Status</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>

        <TableBody>
          {items.map((order: Order) => {

            const createdAtDate = new Date(order.createdAt);

            if (isNaN(createdAtDate.getTime())) {
              console.error('Invalid date for order:', order);
              return null;
            }

            const createdAtMonth = format(createdAtDate, 'LLL').toUpperCase();
            const createdAtDay = format(createdAtDate, 'd');
            const totalAmount = numeral(order.total).format(`${'RSD'}0,0.00`);

            return (
              <TableRow
                hover
                key={order._id}
                onClick={() => onSelect?.(order._id)}
                sx={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
              >
                <TableCell sx={{ alignItems: 'center', display: 'flex' }}>
                  <Box
                    sx={{
                      backgroundColor: (theme) =>
                        theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'neutral.800' : 'neutral.200',
                      borderRadius: 2,
                      maxWidth: 'fit-content',
                      ml: 5,
                      p: 1,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Typography align="center" variant="subtitle2">
                      {createdAtMonth}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography align="center" variant="h6">
                      {createdAtDay}
                    </Typography>
                  </Box>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">
                  <Typography variant="subtitle2">{order.orderNumber}</Typography>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <Typography color="text.secondary" variant="body2">
                    RSD {totalAmount}
                  </Typography>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">
                  {
                    order.paymentMethod == 'cash-on-delivery' ? 'Pouzećem'
                      : order.paymentMethod == 'cash' ? 'Gotovinom'
                        : order.paymentMethod == 'check' ? 'Čekom'
                          : order.paymentMethod == 'credit card' ? 'Kreditnom karticom'
                            : order.paymentMethod == 'paypal' ? 'PayPal' : 'Nepoznato'
                  }
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">{order.customer.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">{order.customer.email}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">
                  <SeverityPill color={
                    order.status == 'pending' ? 'warning' :
                      order.status == 'shipped' ? 'info' :
                        order.status == 'delivered' ? 'success' :
                          order.status == 'cancelled' ? 'error' : 'warning'
                  }>{order.status}</SeverityPill>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
      <TablePagination
        component="div"
        count={count}
        onPageChange={handlePageChange}
        onRowsPerPageChange={handleRowsPerPageChange}
        page={page}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
      />
    </div >
  );
};

OrderListTable.propTypes = {
  count: PropTypes.number,
  items: PropTypes.array,
  onPageChange: PropTypes.func,
  onRowsPerPageChange: PropTypes.func,
  onSelect: PropTypes.func,
  page: PropTypes.number,
  rowsPerPage: PropTypes.number,
};


Creating custom handleRowsPerPageChange and handlePageChange

Solved it by not passing the entire data array but filtering out the array depending on various values:
const visibleRows = useMemo(
() =>
[...items]
.filter(order => tab === 'all' || order.status === tab)
.sort(getComparator(sortDir, sortBy))
.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage),
[items, tab, sortDir, sortBy, page, rowsPerPage],
);

const visibleRows = useMemo(
() =>
  [...items]
    .filter(order => tab === 'all' || order.status === tab)
    .sort(getComparator(sortDir, sortBy))
    .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage),
[items, tab, sortDir, sortBy, page, rowsPerPage],

);
I thought if you pass down data to MUI table that it is automatically going to handle all paginations and what not. I was so wrong :)
